# Gradle subproject conditional plugin configuration with gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

This is how I've previously configured subprojects in gradle if a certain plugin was present:

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    plugins.withType(com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 29
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm not working with groovy anymore. How can I achieve the same thing with gradle kotlin DSL?

Biggest problem here seems to be to find a way to access the android extension, I can't seem to access it using `android` nor `extensions.findByType(com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension::class.java)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a [precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins), which I applied to all subprojects.

`buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2")
}
```

`buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/android-libary.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    ...
}
```

`subProject/build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    `android-library`
}
```